# How to return from a method an asynchronous value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is not a duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) I know that JS is asynchronous, what I am looking for is the Vue way to address the problem.

I have a Vue.js page where some data need to be updated based on the response of an API. The code below does not work because `return r.status` returns from the `fetch` and not from `getName`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    elements: ["400", "401"],
    newelements: []
  },
  methods: {
    // take each elementfrom elemets and update it with the result of an asynchronous function
    updateData() {
      this.elements.forEach(x => {
        this.newelements.push(this.getName(x) + 1000)
        console.log(`processing ${x}`)
      })
    },
    // the asynchronous function
    getName(x) {
      fetch(`https://postman-echo.com/status/${x}`)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(r => {
          console.log(`received status ${r.status}`)
          // here I return from fetch, but I would like r.status to be returned by getName
          return r.status
        })
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.updateData()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="el in elements">{{el}}</div>
  <div v-for="el in newelements">{{el}}</div>
</div>
```

Which is the correct approach to update newelements?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: no, this was the first suggestion when writing the question. I am not trying to understand that JS is asynchronous but the right way, in Vue, to manage these situations.

Comment: it's the same question though, and the answers to it still apply. Your issue is nothing to do with Vue. (I don't actually know Vue very well.)

Comment: Well getName *can't* return the value, only a *promise* of it; I think you'd still get value reading the canonical, fixing your basic mistakes and focusing on any Vue-specific problem that remains.

Answer (score 0):

make a property function in the object and then return it something like

```
getName: (x) =>{
     return fetch(`https://postman-echo.com/status/${x}`)
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(r => {
          console.log(`received status ${r.status}`)
          // here I return from fetch, but I would like r.status to be returned by getName
          return r.status
        })
    },
```

Comment: That's actually no different from just `return fetch(...)` in a non-async function. It's still the correct answer, but using `async/await` here feels cumbersome.

Comment: @Robuin Zigmond it's fixed  thanks for the feedback